# center item in carouselView

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am struggling to get my item centered in the carousel view, as simple as this sounds for same reason the item always starts at starts.
I need to display the items one at the time.

```
 <StackLayout  x:Name="innerStack"     
                  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label Text="tesyt"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
        <CarouselView HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" BackgroundColor="Blue" 
              
                      x:Name="carousel" 
                      HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                      HeightRequest="500"
                      
        >   <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal" ItemSpacing="0"/>
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
          
            <CarouselView.ItemsSource    >
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type Label}">
                    <Label Text="tesyt" TextColor="Green" Margin="10,0,0,0"   
                     ></Label>
                    <Label Text="tesyt" TextColor="Brown"></Label>
                </x:Array>
            </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
        </CarouselView>
    
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried [SnapPoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/scrolling#snap-points)?

Answer (score 0):

> I am struggling to get my item centered in the carousel view。

If you want to set item center in carouselview, you can set `HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"` and  `VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"` for item in carouselview datatemplate.

And I find there are some error for carouselview.itemsource, you can refer to [x:Array markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/consuming#xarray-markup-extension) firstly, you can also take a look the following code:

```
<CarouselView
            x:Name="carousel"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            HeightRequest="500"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="20" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

            <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>mono</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                    <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                    <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                    <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                    <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame
                            Margin="20"
                            BorderColor="Red"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            HasShadow="True"
                            HeightRequest="50"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                Text="{Binding .}"
                                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        </Frame>


                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
        </CarouselView>
```